# Using @ConfigurationProperties statically - such as on @RequestMapping

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-web

Let's ignore for a moment whether doing this is a great idea, but I'm creating  Spring Boot AutoConfiguration for an internal library and as part of this I want to auto-register a Controller that accepts GET/POST/DELETE requests (it is responsible for setting/clearing a cookie value for application testing purposes)

The issue is that I would like the request mapping path to be configurable by the end user. I have a `@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "my.configs")` class that contains all the configuration values with their defaults for example: `private String path = "default-path"`

Ideally i'd be able to reference this in my controller like so: `@RequestMapping(path=${my.configs.path})` but this does not work, Spring reports that it is unable to find that configuration parameter, if I place it into a properties file instead of into a the type-safe `@ConfigurationProperties` it works as expected.

I know I could get around this by putting a default value into the Request mapping, but I'd like to understand just what is happening here, and why I cannot statically refer environment variables read / defaulted into `@ConfigurationProperties` in the way that I can those defined in files.

Answer (score 0):

`@RequestMapping` is a Spring MVC annotation and it gets processed by Spring MVC - no matter if it is all wrapped in Spring Boot app or not.

`@ConfiguationProperties` is on the other hand 100% Spring Boot code and to my knowledge both types of properties are processed at different moments during Spring Context startup lifecycle.